# Annotation processing does not work with lombok and java

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I am working on my own multi modules project, where I am using lombok.
The problem occured when i wanted to start the application, and terminal showed error:

`java: Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles. Please ensure that all modules from cycle [domain,service] are excluded from annotation processing`

So I turned off the annotation processing in project settings
[image]

And there are no more errors with `modules` annotation processing, but there is the new error.
My classes which use `lombok` does not recognize `builder` method
`java: cannot find symbol symbol: method builder()` because lombok require annotation processing - even intellij shows message: `Do you want to enable lombok annotations?` when I turn on intellij.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: An  option is to *eliminate* "module cycles"!(?;) (so depend only unidirectional! `service -> domain` (as the names imply), *and not* `domain -> service`! )

Comment: holy... it works, thanks man xD

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I solved this problem with help of `@xerx593` user.

The main reason why it was not working was this part of error:
`modules from cycle [domain,service]` which means that there was a module cycle in my project.

I have got three modules: `domain`, `service` and `ui` where
`service` module is contingent on `domain` module and
`ui` module is contingent on `service`
so the structure looks like this: `domain` -> `service` -> `ui`:

my `pom.xml` in `ui` module should implement `service` module dependency

my `pom.xml` in `service` module should implement `domain` module dependency

and `pom.xml` in `domain` module should not implement any of `ui` and `service` dependency

but because of my fault, I implemented `service` dependency in `domain` pom.xml and there was the problem with module cycle `dmoain` -> `service` -> `domain`

After i deleted this `service` dependency in `domain` module, everything works!

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, I conclude:

There is a (dependency) cycle in your modules:

- domain and
- service

Unfortunately the error message doesn't recommend you to *elliminate* these cycles, but (rather gently and task focused) only to "exclude them from pre-processing" (which is of course *needed* by lombok et.al.)

To proof yet (when you google "java module cycles", then you hit only *this problem* on the top results ..whereas "java module cycles good or bad?" brought me here:

[Why are cyclic imports considered so evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/why-are-cyclic-imports-considered-so-evil)
), but I think "cyclic modules" is a "anti-module-pattern", and as long your "system" ist small and over-viewable: **Break these cycles & avoid them!**

---

So in your case, I would avoid any imports from `service` to `domain`

> so depend only unidirectional! `service -> domain` ..., *and not* `domain -> service`!

, which will re-enable your pre-proccessing & lombok.

Answer (score 0):

the question itself may need a little bit more context, but in the meantime, looking at lombok's setup for IDEA might help you https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij. TLDR when working with lombok on IDEA you can use this extension to have hints without rebuilding the whole project (since annotation processing kicks in when running the compiler).